# Integration by Parts help?

Tags: integration, complex-integration

Show $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sigma^2/(4kt)}(\sigma^2 +2\sigma x+x^2)d\sigma = 2kt+x^2$

Comment: Split into into three, compute each term in turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will ignore the first factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}}$ for the moment. You just need to split the integral in summands like this:

$$I= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sigma^2 e^{-\sigma^2/(4kt)} d\sigma$$
and
$$II= 2x \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sigma e^{-\sigma^2/(4kt)} d\sigma$$
and
$$III= x^2\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\sigma^2/(4kt)} d\sigma.$$
Then factor $I$ can be rewritten as:

$$I= \sqrt{2\pi (2kt)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sigma^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (2kt)}} e^{-\sigma^2/(4kt)} d\sigma = \sqrt{2\pi (2kt)} * (2kt) $$
where the last equality follows because the integral appearing above is the second order moment of a centered Gaussian random variable with variance $2kt$.

The second is zero since it is the integral of an odd function over a symmetric region (also the mean of a centered normal random variable)
$$II=0$$
Finally,
$$III=\sqrt{2\pi (2kt)} x^2 \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (2kt)}} e^{-\sigma^2/(4kt)} d\sigma = \sqrt{2\pi (2kt)} x^2. $$

Now if you put altogether you get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}  e^{-\sigma^2/(4kt)}(\sigma^2+2\sigma + x^2) d\sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}}(\sqrt{2\pi (2kt)} * (2kt) +0+x^2\sqrt{2\pi (2kt)})= 2kt + x^2.$$